# G Sheet How to get average duration time?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a serie of time duration which are a result of a formula in a column formatted as Duration as well

```
Duration :
80:08:00
53:05:00
50:20:00
86:21:00
59:56:00
44:27:00
#VALUE!
35:44:00
39:29:00
133:45:00
35:07:00
32:20:00
.../...
```

I would like to get the MIN, MAX, and AVERAGE Value. For the Average I tried this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(E2:E305)))
```

I've got this error :

```
#VALUE! ERROR TIMEVALUE parameter '' cannot be parsed to date/time
```

How exclude the cell without any values inside ?

Comment: Try FILTER or QUERY functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Average**
`=query({arrayformula(N($A$2:$A$13))}; "select avg(Col1) where Col1<>0  label avg(Col1) '' ")`

**Minimum**
`=min(query(arrayformula(N($A$2:$A$13));"select Col1 where Col1<>0 label Col1 'min'"))`

**Maximum**
`=MAX(query(arrayformula(N($A$2:$A$13));"select Col1 where Col1<>0 label Col1 'min'"))`

Things to note:

- In each case, the values in the "Duration" column must be converted to numeric. This is done by using the `N()` function.
- The Max and Min formula are made outside the query.
- The `where` clause includes the condition: `Col1<>0`

Comment: You gave me  the idea of this working formula `=AVERAGE(N($A$2:$A$13))`

Comment: On the Average formula, the not equal operator is wrong: `Col1!=0` should be `Col1<>0`, by the other hand your spreadsheet might require to use semicolon `;` as argument separator instead of comma `,`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You [mention](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/139822/g-sheet-how-to-get-average-duration-time#comment128343_139854):

> *You gave me the idea of this working formula `=AVERAGE(N($A$2:$A$13))`*

**Be careful. The above formula will give you wrong results so you should not use it**

### The correct formulas

Instead you should use the formulas by [Tedinoz](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/139854/117311) OR these simpler ones to find the

**average value**


```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(A2:A))
```

**min value**


```
=MIN(QUERY(A2:A))
```

**max value**


```
=MAX(QUERY(A2:A))
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**

You need neither the `Arrayformula` nor the `TIMEVALUE` functions.
You can simply use the following formulas:

```
=MIN(E2:E305)
=MAX(E2:E305)
=AVERAGE(E2:E305)
```

[image: max, min, average of time duration]

Comment: That's working because you carried out #VALUE!  , in my case more than 300 lignes and I would like all the cells with #VALUE!  or ERROR are not taken in account.